# Blazor, blazor js, and other js throw an error

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

When I want to use a variable in a link (parameter) all js files throw console errors
When I remove the parameter from the link everything works fine
Page:

```
@page "/PollShow/{id:int}"

@code{

 [Parameter]

 public int Id { get; set; } = 1;

}
```

this is my _host.cshtml

```
@page "/"
@namespace Polls.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin 2 - Dashboard</title>
    <link href="~/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Custom styles for this page -->
    <link href="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body id="page-top">
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Page level custom scripts -->
    <script src="js/demo/datatables-demo.js"></script>

    <script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

error console when i use link with parameter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KxSi.png)

Comment: Please include the error as text in your question.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me, but it's not what you can see that kills you!  Strip all the JS files out except "blazor.server.js" and test.  Use a standard _hosts.cshtml and test.  Get a working system and then add back till it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the exacte same name for the parameter. Its case sensitive

```
@page "/PollShow/{Id:int}"
```